# Identifying a cooperative escape game

Tags: identify-this-game

**Setup:** Maps are generated by placing provided tiles next to each other, which were either shuffled or placed according to some guide (don't remember). I remember there were distinct tile types with slides and ladders, and the ultimate goal was to escape the generated map. There may have also been a real-life time limit (hourglass?) and restrictions on communication.

I've searched high and low for the game but it's pretty hard to identify a game by these features. It's **definitely not** Alien Labryinth or Space Maze though.

Comment: Have you searched by mechanic? If not, I would start by Elapsed Real Time Ending:
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2882/elapsed-real-time-ending

Comment: What was the theme/setting? Was it horror themed with tiles building out a haunted house? If so, I don't know the name off the top of my head but I have access to a copy and figure it out tonight. Regardless, the setting would help in identifying it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Magic Maze](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/209778/magic-maze) has slides and ladders and a real-world time limit.

[image]

Comment: FYI, on BoardGameArena they recently issued an [alpha release](https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=magicmaze) of it, it's lots of fun; currently, only accessible to premium members and gametesters, but if it gets approved for release, will be generally accessible.

Comment: @smci mostly true, just one small correction: I don't think you need premium to access alpha stage games, just a ton of played games on a record. Also, once you've been invited to alpha game by someone, you can create it yourself.

Comment: @Deo: ok. BGA Premium is a nice Christmas gift. Anyway my point was everyone who likes this fun game (it's kind of like Gauntlet for geeks), help it get out of alpha and beta into general release, on BGA.

Comment: This is definitely the game we played. She vaguely remembers sushi but there definitely isn't a sushi-related one.

Answer (score 1):

Magic Maze mentioned already seems like a good fit. Other options could be: **Escape:Curse of the Temple** (or another one from Escape series), and maybe **Sub Terra** (no hourglass, game is entirely turn-based, but it does have a timer)